# python selenium/soup not scrolling and printing entire job containers in linkedined

Tags: selenium, beautifulsoup, scroll, linkedin-api

Here's the problem statement: The `base_site` link below takes us to a job search URL.

There are small containers that show jobs on the left pane of the webpage.
The problem is that with this code I can only see 7 containers as output.

For example, it shows the 1st seven job result locations in the output whereas I am expecting all of them to be shown in the output. For this, I am using `scrolltoview` but that doesn't seem to help as well.
What is it that I'm missing?

```
from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from time import sleep
    
    def get_driver():
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\abc\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
        path = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\chromedriver.exe'
        options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(path, options=options)
        text_search = 'Product Development Engineer'
        location_search = 'california'
        # base_site = 'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs'
        base_site = 'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?currentJobId=2638809245&f_E=3%2C4&f_JT=F&f_SB2=3&f_TPR=r60' \
                    '4800&geoId=102095887&keywords=product%20development%20engineer&location=California%2C%20United%20States&sortBy=R'
        headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/"
                "70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"}
        driver.get(base_site)
        parsing_job_data(driver, base_site, headers)
    
    def parsing_job_data(driver, base_site, headers):
        try:
    
            html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
            html.send_keys(Keys.END)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
            results = soup.find_all('div', class_="job-card-container relative job-card-list job-card-container--clickable "
                                                  "job-card-list--underline-title-on-hover jobs-search-results-list__list-"
                                                  "item--active jobs-search-two-pane__job-card-container--viewport-tracking"
                                                  "-0")
            sleep(1)
            each_container = soup.select('[class*="occludable-update"]', limit=20)
            for container in each_container:
                element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("artdeco-entity-lockup__caption")
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
                element.click()
    
                job_title = container.find('a', class_='disabled ember-view job-card-container__link job-card-list__title').text
                location = container.find('li', class_='job-card-container__metadata-item').text
    
   
                job_title = job_title.strip()
                location = location.strip()
                print(job_title, ', ', location)
    
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        get_driver()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import trio
import httpx
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0"
}


async def get_soup(content):
    return BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')


allin = []


async def worker(channel):
    async with channel:
        async for num in channel:
            async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=None) as client:
                client.headers.update(headers)

                params = {
                    "currentJobId": "2638809245",
                    "f_E": "3,4",
                    "f_JT": "F",
                    "f_SB2": "3",
                    "f_TPR": "r604800",
                    "geoId": "102095887",
                    "keywords": "product development engineer",
                    "location": "California, United States",
                    "sortBy": "R",
                    "position": "1",
                    "pageNum": "0",
                    "start": num
                }
                r = await client.get('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs-guest/jobs/api/seeMoreJobPostings/search', params=params)
                soup = await get_soup(r.text)
                goal = [(x.h3.get_text(strip=True), x.select_one('.job-search-card__location').get_text(strip=True))
                        for x in soup.select('.base-search-card__info')]
                allin.extend(goal)


async def main():
    async with trio.open_nursery() as nurse:

        sender, receiver = trio.open_memory_channel(0)

        async with receiver:
            for _ in range(2):
                nurse.start_soon(worker, receiver.clone())

            async with sender:
                for num in range(0, 450, 25):
                    await sender.send(num)

    df = pd.DataFrame(allin, columns=["Title", "Location"])
    print(df)
    #df.to_csv('result.csv', index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    trio.run(main)
```

Output:

```
                                      Title             Location
0                Packaging Process Engineer          Fremont, CA
1                          Project Engineer          Oakland, CA
2    Process Engineer- Materials and Fibers    Santa Clarita, CA
3            Senior Product Design Engineer           Carson, CA
4                           Design Engineer       Sacramento, CA
..                                      ...                  ...
436           Software Development Engineer           Irvine, CA
437           Software Development Engineer        Sunnyvale, CA
438           Software Development Engineer  San Luis Obispo, CA
439    Software Development Engineer - Luna           Irvine, CA
440           Software Development Engineer           Irvine, CA

[441 rows x 2 columns]
```